How to properly handle concurrency to avoid duplicates in C# entityframework + MySql?
I have an aspnet6.0 application which is creating duplicate records when concurrent requests are made within milliseconds difference. Logic is very simple. A group needs to be created but it's name is validated from database to see if it already exists. If it does exists then it is returned otherwise new group is created and returned. MySQL is being used and name column is indexed as well. I was thinking to add Task.Delay but that doesn't sound very promising. I am looking for a performant and efficient solution. Tried cache as well but issue still persists.

Requests timeline:


this seems weird, why would adding some delay solve anything? you need to put that whole thing in a transaction.

This is a decision that should involve some context - what is a group? What does creating a group mean (is it just assigning an id or are you saving an object with many attributes as well)? Why are you creating the same group twice - is this happening a lot, just an edge case? What do you want to do when a group already exists that you are trying to create ... just use the group that exists? Or throw errors? It seems like the short and obvious answer is if the group exists then just use it ... why is it a problem?) ... also agree that the "concurrency" issue is just you need transactions.

group is id, name , date. It's happening a lot now because this endpoint is used extensively. As said if group already exists then return the existing one else create new one. (id is used in both cases). But requests are received almost in exact same instant, which is causing to insert duplicates.

Define a UNIQUE constraint on the group name.
Then if the insert tries to save a group name that exists, it will throw a duplicate key exception.
This should be rare, if you first checked for presence of the group by name. In other words, you'll get a duplicate only if your check for the group found none, but in the moment after checking, some other session inserted that group name.
Handle the exception by re-reading the group from the database, because it is now present.
